# MYSQL auto_increment_increment

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to auto_increment two different tables in a single mysql database, the first by multiples of 1 and the other by 5 is this possible using the auto_increment feature as I seem to only be able to set auto_increment_increment globally.

If auto_increment_increment is not an option what is the best way to replicate this

Comment: Maybe you could add a plain auto_increment field + a trigger which calculates the multiplied value and puts into the proper field after each insert/update.

Comment: Seems like the thing to do if this functionality does not exist, I just really thought that it would :) Thanks

Comment: I'm curious why one would ever need to change the increment interval?

Comment: @eggyval One legitimate reason is if you have replicated databases and each needs its number space for the primary key. Usually, one of the databases uses the even PK values, and the other the odd PK values, therefore, you need an increment of 2 for both databases and different start values (at least that's how it's usually done in Oracle, not 100% sure about MySQL).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated version: only a single `id` field is used. This is very probably not atomic, so use inside a transaction if you need concurrency:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4ed8/1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
   id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_kangaroo_id BEFORE INSERT ON person FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE newid INT;

  SET newid = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
               FROM information_schema.TABLES
               WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
               AND TABLE_NAME = 'person'
              );

  IF NEW.id AND NEW.id >= newid THEN
    SET newid = NEW.id;
  END IF;

  SET NEW.id = 5 * CEILING( newid / 5 );
END;
```

Old, non working "solution" (the before insert trigger can't see the current auto increment value):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4f9a/1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
   secretid  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   id        INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( secretid )
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TRIGGER update_kangaroo_id BEFORE UPDATE ON person FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.id = NEW.secretid * 5;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_kangaroo_id BEFORE INSERT ON person FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.id = NEW.secretid * 5; -- NEW.secretid is empty = unusuable!
END;
```

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer, because you accepted a non-working solution.