# Working with primary key as auto increment in MySQL

Tags: mysql, yii2

[image]There are two types of insertion accrued in my table

1.From user
   2.Through migration (using Yii2 php framework)

This table id's are used as foreign keys in other tables so I want that these id's should not be changed.
   The problem is that I have two different environments that are a local database and live database (the application is live).
  let there is one record in a local database and 1 in live server locally I select my account as a user and insert 1 more record and than insert then third one record through migration.
  Now if this migration runs on a live server, the primary key 2 will be inserted because it had one record while on local it's key is 3 because 1 record was inserted by a user.
Kindly help me how to handle this scenario

now consider that this table having 8 records in one database(on live server) and 9 records on another server(database).i want to insert new record whose id should be same in both databases and insertion is through migration where same migration is applied on both databases(server).As there any way to set different ranges of primary key which is auto increment or any solution appreciated

Comment: In effect you have 2 live databases?(live and local).

Comment: You're hardcoding IDs of records in your code?

Comment: @rob006  if the record is inserted by user(other than admin) than auto and in case of migration(admin i am hard coding it)

Comment: @P.Salmon no local mean local host only one live database

Comment: Why you're hardcoding IDs in migrations? You should not specify ID and allow DBMS to generate correct ID.

Comment: @rob006 to keep unique id's  because there is 3 nested hiraracy i.e one table primary key is added as foreign key in another table

Comment: You can get inserted ID using `getLastInsertID()` - you should use this ID in your migrations to insert related records.

Comment: As P.Salmon pointed out, you seem to basically have two databases that each need to assign autoincrement ids, but you get problems if/since they overlap ids. There is a general solution for this: use different ids on the two databases (e.g. on live, ids are 1,3,5,7, on local 2,4, and you then simply merge those). See e.g. the [MySQL build-in-solution for this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14373582) (in case it's not clear: each server gets a different offset and the same increment; caution: it's a server wide setting) or a [manual implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11308438)

Comment: The likelihood of being able to keep the 2 data bases in sync is low, Think delete,insert on duplicate key, rollback etc etc. Both dbs are independent entities and will respond to events which may be unique to one but may never occur on the other..